# Iterate over Guava Table with JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl, guava

I am using the Table class (specifically the HashBasedTable) from the Guava library (formerly Google Collections). I am using Spring MVC and after packaging my beans into this Table in my controller class, I want to iterate over it on my JSP page.

How would I go about doing that? Below is a simplified version of what I'd been trying.

```
  <c:forEach var="rowElement" items="${resultsCL.rowKeySet}">
      <c:forEach var="columnElement" items="${resultsCL.columnKeySet}">
          ${resultsCL.get(rowElement, columnElement)}">
       </c:forEach>
   </c:forEach>
```

Comment: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'columnKeySet' not found on type com.google.common.collect.HashBasedTable....I get that error when I run it. EDIT - I know this would work in normal java code - could it be I'm not understanding the EL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rowKeySet` and `columnKeySet` are not getter-methods, so you can't call them with `bean.property` syntax. You need to invoke the methods. I.e. `resultCL.rowKeySet()` and `resultCL.columnKeySet()`

Note that this may not work with older versions of EL that do not support method invocations.

Comment: Yep. If your version of JSP EL does not support arbitrary method calls (which happens relatively often), you'll need to expose the key set views in your model under a different name... Or use an EL function to access it.